# How to search a matrix for "1", and once found, check all diagonals of that element for other "1"s (python)

Tags: python

I have an 8x8 matrix, each element is either 0 or 1:

```
matrix = [
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

Now I want a for loop that locates each 1 and checks the diagonal of each 1 and counts how many 1s there are on each diagonal, storing that count to a variable.

ChatGPT gave me this, but it doesn't seem to work properly, if I make a matrix where the 1s don't overlap on the diagonals, it will output "4", but it should be "0", as in, there are no 1s with other 1s in their diagonal

```
def check_diagonals(matrix, row, col):
    # Define the directions for diagonals: up-left, up-right, down-left, down-right
    directions = [(-1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, -1), (1, 1)]

    # List to store the values found in diagonals
    diagonal_count=0

    for dr, dc in directions:
        r, c = row, col
        while 0 <= r < len(matrix) and 0 <= c < len(matrix[0]):
            if(matrix[r][c]==1):
                diagonal_count+=1
            r += dr
            c += dc

    return diagonal_count


def search_and_check(matrix):
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[0])):
            if matrix[i][j] == 1:
                diagonals = check_diagonals(matrix, i, j)
                print("Diagonal count:", diagonals)


# Example usage:
matrix =[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]] 

search_and_check(matrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you traced through this?  That code INCLUDES the starting point in the search.  Since it searches in 4 directions, that initial point gets counted 4 times.

You can work around this by changing

```
        r, c = row, col
```

to

```
        r, c = row+dr, col+dc
```

BTW, note that StackOverflow has a policy against posting or debugging ChatGPT-generated content.  We shouldn't be in the business of debugging code generated by a machine.  Your question should rightly be closed.

Answer (score -1):

I assume this deals with the [eight queens puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle).

As Tim stated, you will need to apply your directions before you hit your `while` loop. Also, your `search_and_check` function should return an overall `count`.

In regards to the directions, the following tuples are related:

- Negative Slope (NW/SE) ~ `(-1, -1)` and `(+1, +1)`
- Positive Slope (NE/SW) ~ `(-1, +1)` and `(+1, -1)`

So we need to check if there are any neighbors in each related direction to determine the count. We do not want to mistakenly increment the `count` by `2` if there are neighbors in both related directions.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def check_diagonals(matrix, row, col):
    directions = [(-1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, -1), (1, 1)]
    neighbors = [0 for _ in directions]
    for i, (dr, dc) in enumerate(directions):
        r, c = row + dr, col + dc
        while 0 <= r < len(matrix) and 0 <= c < len(matrix[0]):
            neighbors[i] += matrix[r][c]
            r, c = r + dr, c + dc
    count = 0
    if neighbors[0] + neighbors[3]:
        count += 1
    if neighbors[1] + neighbors[2]:
        count += 1
    return count


def search_and_check(matrix):
    diagonals = 0
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
            if matrix[i][j] == 1:
                diagonals += check_diagonals(matrix, i, j)
    return diagonals


if __name__ == '__main__':
    board = [
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ]

    print('Overlaps:', search_and_check(board))
```

Here is a deep-dive into understanding how the directions (vectors) correlate with one another (horizontally, vertically, and diagonally):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import functools
import logging
from typing import List, Tuple, Union

Vector = Tuple[int, int]
VectorList = List[Vector]


def bits_to_int(bits: List[int]) -> int:
    """
    Convert a list of bits (0 or 1) to an integer.

    Args:
        bits (List[int]): List of bits.

    Returns:
        int: Integer representation of the binary bits.
    """
    return functools.reduce(lambda res, bit: (res << 1) | bit, bits, 0)


def are_symmetrical(a: Vector, b: Vector) -> bool:
    """
    Check if two vectors are symmetrical by verifying if the sum of their
    corresponding elements is zero.

    Args:
        a (Tuple[int, int]): First vector.
        b (Tuple[int, int]): Second vector.

    Returns:
        bool: True if the vectors are symmetrical, False otherwise.
    """
    return not any(sum(v) for v in zip(a, b))


def determine_axis(direction: Vector) -> Union[str, None]:
    """
    Determine the axis type based on the given direction vector.

    Args:
        direction (Tuple[int, int]): Input vector representing a direction.

    Returns:
        Union[str, None]: Type of axis ('Diagonal', 'Horizontal', 'Vertical') or
        None if unknown.
    """
    x, y = direction
    axis_mapping = [None, "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Diagonal"]
    return axis_mapping[bits_to_int([abs(x), abs(y)])]


def find_symmetrical(directions: VectorList, direction: Vector) -> Union[Vector, None]:
    """
    Find a symmetrical vector in a list of directions.

    Args:
        directions (List[Tuple[int, int]]): List of direction vectors.
        direction (Tuple[int, int]): Input vector.

    Returns:
        Union[Tuple[int, int], None]: Symmetrical vector or None if not found.
    """
    return next((d for d in directions if are_symmetrical(direction, d)), None)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Configure logging format and level
    logging.basicConfig(format='[%(levelname)s] %(asctime)s %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)

    # Generate a list of directions using a nested list comprehension
    directions = [(x, y) for x in range(-1, 2) for y in range(-1, 2) if x or y]
    logging.debug(f"Generated Directions: {directions}")

    # Create a dictionary to store symmetries lookup indices
    symmetries = {
        i: directions.index(find_symmetrical(directions, d))
        for i, d in enumerate(directions)
    }
    logging.debug(f"Symmetry Lookup Indices: {symmetries}")

    # Group direction pairs by their axis
    axis = {}
    for k, v in map(lambda e: list(map(lambda x: directions[x], e)), symmetries.items()):
        axis.setdefault(determine_axis(k), []).append((k, v))
    logging.debug(f"Direction Pairs Grouped by Axis: {axis}")

    # Display direction pairs along with their axis
    for k, v in axis.items():
        logging.info(f"{k}: {', '.join(map(lambda p: ' -> '.join(map(str, p)), v))}")
```